# Where do I get the "ucode" firmware for the Intel Centrino 6205 wireless adapter?

Tags: 12.04, intel-wireless, firmware, proprietary

Anyone knows where can I find the iwlwifi-6000g2a-ucode-6.ucode firmware?

Comment: By "ucode" do you mean a microcode/proprietary driver? Cf. http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Intel_Centrino_Advanced-N_6205

Answer (score 1):

The firmware *should* be included with the kernel, but in case you need it separately, here's the tarball from the official Intel Linux Wireless drivers group:

http://intellinuxwireless.org/iwlwifi/downloads/iwlwifi-6000g2a-ucode-17.168.5.3.tgz

Comment: That tarball does NOT contain "iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode". It contains "iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode", so, again, where can one download "iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode"?

Comment: It is also a dead link currently.

Answer (score 1):

check this link:
it contains firmwares for multiple intel WiFi chips,,
http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi?highlight=%28ucode%29

Answer (score 0):

You can find *iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode* in the tarball *iwlwifi-6000g2a-ucode-18.168.6.1.tgz* that you can download here:
http://intellinuxwireless.org/?n=downloads&f=mac80211

Comment: Please explain how to use that file for the OP and future users.